# Scrolling UIScrollView from UIWebView with two finger?

Tags: uiwebview, uiscrollview, ios5, uigesturerecognizer

I have to deal with some web content whose js dynamically change content's location by using the browser size but if i put UIWebView with the size 320*460 everything messed up. (Every object come on each other.) So i put large UIScrollView with large UIWebView to solve this problem. My aim is to scroll scroll view with two finger touch so i can move any place on the web view.

```
for (id gestureRecognizer in scrollview.gestureRecognizers) {     
    if ([gestureRecognizer  isKindOfClass:[UIPanGestureRecognizer class]])
    {
        UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGR = gestureRecognizer;
        panGR.minimumNumberOfTouches = 2;              
        panGR.maximumNumberOfTouches = 2;
    }
}
```

But in this condition i have another problem that i can't figure out:

*When none of finger touches directly to scrollview (when all iPhone screen is filled with webview) i can't scroll scroll view*

**I somehow need to detect two finger touches on uiwebview to use these touches to scroll scroll view.**

Note:

`[[[webview subviews] lastObject] setScrollEnabled:NO];`

doesn't work because js use touch on uiwebview to move object dynamically.

Thank you.